# EndpointNotFoundException when working through tutorials in Learning WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I am working through the book Learning WCF and on the first tutorial lab **HelloIndigo** I am receiving the following error.

Could not connect to http://localhost:8000/HelloIndigo/HelloIndigoService. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8000.

It appears in the Client project on the line string s = proxy.HelloIndigo();

```
EndpointAddress ep = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8000/HelloIndigo/HelloIndigoService");

IHelloIndigoService proxy = ChannelFactory<IHelloIndigoService>.
            CreateChannel(new BasicHttpBinding(), ep);
string s = proxy.HelloIndigo();
Console.WriteLine(s);
Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate Client");
Console.ReadLine();
```

I have intensively googled on this but I am none the wiser.

Can anyone explain the issue and how to remedy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be several things, first things to check are:

- Is the service running?
- Is there an endpoint configured a that address?
- Is there any firewall that is blocking the request?

Try puting the endpoint address in a browser and see if you can browse to it.

Comment: @Shiraz- If I put the endpoint address in a browser I receive a blank page - if I reduce the url to http://localhost:8000/HelloIndigo I receive: This is a Windows© Communication Foundation service Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled. etc...

Comment: @Shiraz - if I try to add as a service reference to another project - I receive... There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:8000/HelloIndigo/HelloIndigoService'.
The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:8000/HelloIndigo/HelloIndigoService'.
Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service http://localhost:8000/HelloIndigo/HelloIndigoService.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched. etc

Comment: In order to add service reference, you must have metadata exchange enabled, this is done in the mex tag

Comment: @Shiraz thanks, Is there anyway to test your bulleted points?

Comment: @Shiraz - figured it out - the Host project and the client were in the  same solution and of course I was only setting the Client as the start-up project - when I opened the Host and Client as two seperate projects and ran them it worked as expected. In the book it says Compile the solution and run the Host project first, followed by the Client project. How do you do this within a solution???

Comment: You can mark more than one project as a startup project, I think that it is in the properties of the solution

Answer (score 2):

In Solution Explorer, right-click the solution and select "Properties".  On the left, Under "Common Properties", select "Startup Project".  On the right, select "Multiple startup projects" - move "Host" to the top and change Action to Start - move "Client" underneath "Host" and change Action to Start.  When you click F5 to debug, studio will first start the Host project in a console app, and then it will start the Client project in a separate console app.